# Centring and keeping same length of bars given dynamic text

Tags: css, react-native

From this situation, where the text is aligned to the left and right

[image]

I need to get to this other situation where:

• the text keeps the previous alignment

• the text is sent to a new line if the text exceeds a specific width

• the bars are centered to their relative box

[image]

**In this way I can maximise the length of the bars**

This is what I'm currently getting using this code:

[image]

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 10, }}>
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#C4C4C4' }}>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'right', marginVertical: 1, maxWidth: 60, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>Test Test Test</Text>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'right', marginVertical: 1, maxWidth: 60, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>T2</Text>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'right', marginVertical: 1, maxWidth: 60, backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>Test2</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <View style={{ height: 14, backgroundColor: 'red', marginVertical: 1, marginHorizontal: 2, borderRadius: 15 }} />
                        <View style={{ height: 14, backgroundColor: 'green', marginVertical: 1, marginHorizontal: 2, borderRadius: 15 }} />
                        <View style={{ height: 14, backgroundColor: 'grey', marginVertical: 1, marginHorizontal: 2, borderRadius: 15 }} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#C4C4C4' }}>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left', marginVertical: 1, maxWidth: 60, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>Test Test Test</Text>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left', marginVertical: 1, maxWidth: 60, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>Test1</Text>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left', marginVertical: 1, maxWidth: 60, backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>Te</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
```

**EDIT**

If I'm gonna arrange it by rows, I'm gonna lose the same length for each bar.

If I'm gonna fix the length of bars, then I'm not able to utilise the full width of the pink area

[image]

```
<View style={{ marginBottom: 10, backgroundColor: 'pink' }}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 5 }}>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'right', marginVertical: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>Test Test Test</Text>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 14, backgroundColor: 'red', marginVertical: 1, marginHorizontal: 2, borderRadius: 15 }} />
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left', marginVertical: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>Test Test Test</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 5 }}>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'right', marginVertical: 1, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>T2</Text>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 14, backgroundColor: 'green', marginVertical: 1, marginHorizontal: 2, borderRadius: 15 }} />
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left', marginVertical: 1, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>Test1</Text>

                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 5 }}>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'right', marginVertical: 1, backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>Test2</Text>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 14, backgroundColor: 'grey', marginVertical: 1, marginHorizontal: 2, borderRadius: 15 }} />
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left', marginVertical: 1, backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>Te</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
```

Comment: Arrange it by rows, not columns

Comment: Css-Grid would be ideal here

Comment: @yainspan done it but then I'm gonna lose the same length of the bars which has to be kept. Please check the edits

Comment: @Paulie_D there is css-grid for react native? oO